# Rails: `rescue in apply': Use rvm gem 1.11.3.5 or newer. (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm trying to use an application template from [one of the RailsApps tutorials](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-devise-rspec-cucumber.html).  I'm getting this `RuntimeError`.

```
...  
extras  creating RVM gemset 'myApp'
     run    rvm rvmrc trust from "."
Marked /Users/dB/railsApp/myApp/Gemfile as trusted
  extras  switching to gemset 'myApp'
https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/master/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber-template.rb:1096:in `rescue in apply': Use rvm gem 1.11.3.5 or newer. (RuntimeError)
```

I'm puzzled because I'm using rvm version 1.14.2, which is `>` than the version they seem to be asking for (1.11.3.5).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rvm lib code was extracted to a gem at version 1.11.3, since then only bugfixes were applied so no version bump was done except the forth digit to show updates.

rvm installed the gem for you during installation of new ruby as the rvm gem is included in global.gems file.

Comment: So you're saying that the RVM command line utility and the "RVM gem" are two distinct things with different version numbers. I didn't understand that before, but now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out.  I was using an old version of Ruby.  I'd downloaded the latest one, but I'd forgotten to set it as current in the RVM. Once I made the new version current, this error went away.